# Check string syntax with block limitation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need make a regex expression to validate an external string. I'm building a PHP FW and it have a `load()` function. It load a view from `views/` dir and sometimes I need receive an external string from user, what is insecure.

Currently my regex is: `~^([a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]*/?)+$~` and it can validate, for instance:

- `hello`: true
- `hello/world`: true
- `hello/world/`: true
- `../pass`: false

So, it works very good. But if I receive an external string from user, for instance: `"hello/{$world}"` he will can send `$world = "sub/dir"`, and it is very insecure, in some cases. I want limit it by use a special character (too can be done by another function, that test it, but I want inline too, because it's more simple).

I think about make a "limitation block" like: `"hello/[{$world}]"` what mean that all that I have between colchetes not can have a slash, example based on:

- `hello/world`: true
- `hello/world/test`: false

So, what I need to change on my regex to it works?

**Edit**

The question is: I need match a string, for instance:

```
function load($path) {
    if(preg_match($path,...))
        include ...;
}
```

If `$path` is `abc/def/ghi` or `abc/[def]/ghi` it's ok, but if it is `abc/[def/ghi]` it'll fail because I cannot have `/` inside of a `[block limitator]`.

**More information**:

- `[$test] => hello`: true
- `[$test] => hello/world`: false
- `[$a]/[$b] => hello/world`: true
- `[$a]/[$b] => hello`: false (need $b too)
- `[$a[$b]]`: is not possible, false

I will parse result to remove the block limitation after, I just need check if it is valid.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i think there shoud be a slash too :
`[$a]/[$b] => hello/`: false (need $b too)

Comment: Ah okay, better now :) But into which concrete problem did you run? Writing the regex? You wrote you had already some start, so probably you can phrase what's stopping you to continue? So the answer could be more helpful then.

Comment: Okay, the *more information* part is still unclear. What is `$test` or `$a` or `$b`? Are those *variables*? If so, which naming convention does this follow?

Comment: `$test`, `$a` and `$b` are external variables, passed by `$_GET` for instance, I need test if an external variable passed by some user is secure to include a file, without accept subdir *inside of block only*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood correctly, it could be something like this

expanded:

```
^
  ( [a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]* /?
    |
    \[ [a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]* \] (?=/|$) /?
  )+
$
```

**edit**

or, more factored:

```
^
  ( 
    (?:  [a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]*
       | \[ [a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]* \] (?=/|$)
    )
    /?
  )+
$
```

and if you don't mind extra unicode chars:

`~^(?:(?:[\w\x7f-\xff]*|\[[\w\x7f-\xff]*\](?=/|$))/?)+$~`

**edit2** squeze out out the last bit of factoring:

`~^(?:(?:[a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]*|\[[a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]*\])(?=/|$)/?)+$~`
or
`~^(?:(?:[\w\x7f-\xff]*|\[[\w\x7f-\xff]*\])(?=/|$)/?)+$~`

Remember, an empty string, or even `///` and this regex will match.

Comment: Great! I'll test it and I will talk about my result as soon I can.

Comment: Very good, really. I make a simple change to not accept `[]` changing `*` with `+`. The `///` is normal, works like a file system path yet :) The final code is: `~^(?:(?:[a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]*|\[[a-z_0-9A-Z\x7f-\xff]+\])(?=/|$)/?)+$~` Thanks!